# 500s on route /_ah/stop when deploying new version to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When deploying new versions of the app, we see a number of error logs in our request logs (`projects/my-project/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log`) with status code 500 for the endpoint `/_ah/stop`. These have the message 'Process terminated because the backend was stopped.'.

This creates noise in our alerting, and indicates something is going wrong. It also seems to correlate with other 5xx responses at the same time.

Oddly, the logging from our app indicates the app recieved the requests and responded with a 200 status. We tried adding a handler for `/_ah/stop` that just returns a 200, as we have no particular cleanup work to do on shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the App Engine instance is being shut down. If a version that is serving traffic (requests) is updated, the requests that are in the middle of getting processed will be dropped and an error will be seen.

This can happen if you are deploying new revisions by updating the currently serving revision (e.g. by default with `gcloud app deploy`). By default, each version that you deploy is automatically configured to receive 100% of traffic, and stops previous instances.

To fix this, instead create the version and migrate the traffic gradually to it, like this:

```
VERSION_ID=$(date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S)
gcloud app deploy --version $VERSION_ID --no-promote
gcloud app services set-traffic --splits $VERSION_ID=1 --migrate
```

If you don't already have one, you might need to add a `/_ah/warmup` handler to support this, and a directive in your `app.yaml`:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Also see:

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--promote
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests

Answer (score 0):

This is an AppEngine bug. It seems that (for standard environment) the instance is supposed to intercept the `/_ah/stop` request and handle it.

In the case of a deployment, that intercept doesn't happen, and the request makes it through to the deployed code. If you stop an instance manually by deleting it, the `/_ah/stop` request is correctly intercepted and handled (and doesn't make it through to deployed code).

see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326181160